# Do not compare two values, with if else

Tags: java, android, if-statement

Good morning, my problem is with if else in DialogAlert, when I put four **equal numbers**, it doesn't make the correct function, which would compare pass1 and pass2, but it goes to the function of PIN is different. Why it doesn't compare pass1 and pass2?

Thank you very much.

```
loginbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    String valor1 = pass1.getText().toString();
    String valor2 = pass2.getText().toString(); 

    if ((pass1.getText().toString().length() < 4) || pass2.getText().toString().length() < 4)) { 

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter 4 digits and the same pin", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    pass1.setText("");
    pass1.requestFocus();
    pass2.setText("");

    } else  if (pass1.equals(pass2))  {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Account create", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    alertDialog.dismiss();

    } else {
    pass1.setText("");
    pass1.requestFocus();
    pass2.setText("");
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "The pin is different, makes the same pin", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of comparing the controls :

```
} else if (pass1.equals(pass2))
```

you should compare the Strings contained in the controls :

```
} else if (pass1.getText().toString().equals(pass2.getText().toString()))
```

Comment: Hi Eran, thanks!! works with                                                                                  } else if (pass1.getText().toString().equals(pass2.getText().toString())).                           +1